# Firebase setDoc results in a async/await error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Right now, I am making an app for my client and I have a form that should register a new user. I have initialized my firebase app, both in project and in the console.
I put setDoc operation in my submit function(and I used async/await), but in the console I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

I am making my project using react, if that helps.
Here is my function:

```
const submit = async () => {
        if(name.length >= 3 && surname.length >= 3 && phone.length >= 9 && code.length == 3)
        {
            const userName = name + surname
            const ref = doc(db, 'users', userName)
            const data = {
                name: name,
                surname: surname,
                phone: phone,
                code: code,
                userName: name + surname
            }
            console.log(data)
            await setDoc(ref, data).then((res) => {
                window.alert('Регистрацијата е успешна!')
                router('/')
            })
        }
        if(name.length <= 2) setNameError(true)
        if(surname.length <= 2) setSurnameError(true)
        if(phone.length <= 8) setPhoneError(true)
        if(code.length != 3) setCodeError(true)
        
    }
```

Thanks in advance to the people that will answer this question :)

Answer (score 0):

The `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.` error means that you have to adapt your security rules to allow writing in the `users` collection.

The most basic possible rule would be:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Match any document in the 'users' collection
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: ...;
      allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

But it would allow everyone to write to the collection, so it's not really recommended. However it may be interesting to temporarily use it on a test environment to check that your code is correct.

Read [the doc on security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) in order to find the exact rule corresponding to your needs.

Note that you will probably be interested by the [common pattern](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication) shown in the doc which aims at "making sure users can only read and write their own data".

Comment: Hi @viktormaksimoski, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?